# How can I update a Data table using VaRest and File Helper in Unreal Engine

Tags: json, datatable, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I’m aware we cannot update data tables in blueprints because they are read only HOWEVER, you can update them in run time if the CSV or the file is inside and you change the values by using code from what I have seen in this [Tutorial](https://youtu.be/zuJ2tjZW770).

With that being said there are 2 Pluggins that are very important for what I want to do I will add them here so you can see what they do (this is related to the question Im adding all the detail I can). [File Helper Blueprint Library](https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/file-helper-bp-library?sessionInvalidated=true), [VaRest](https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/varest-plugin).

My idea is to bring DATA from an API as a Json (Thats something VaRest Do) I have it here:

[image]

Is quite simple tbh you set up the link of the API and in this case I want the Json to come as a String so that File Helper can transform it from String to a Csv and then Csv to Data Table:

[image]

However Im not very good at Unreal Engine still trying to figure out a few things and I do not understand how to break the string so that it comes as a CSV and then send it to Data Table.

Before I did try to transform the Json directly in to the Data Table since file helper has an option that goes from Json to Data Table

[image]

(This is disconnected but should be connected to the Callback) All I would get instead of the values properly was Rip and the Data Table wouldnt update.

Before that I try this one as well:

[image]

It would print success and then Rip...

Any help, insight, tutorial, tip, w/e is welcome. I have try bunch of other stuff as well but I dont want to make this longer in the end all I want is to understand how to make it from the String to CSV to see if that attempt will work.

[image]